# Algolia browse returns bad results when searching with numbers

Tags: algolia

I have a handful of records loaded in Algolia.

In Algolia browser, I search for: 1986

Algolia returns matches: 1986, 1980, 1984... 

What's up with that? Is there a setting to fix this?

Here is a screen snapshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aznwg82kclddzno/Screenshot%202016-03-10%2021.21.22.png?dl=0

Here is another one from their own examples:
Search for 2999 and it matches: 2199, 2499, 1999, 999...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c5csanb3f6fpxh/Screenshot%202016-03-10%2021.30.38.png?dl=0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is the result of the typo tolerance which is enabled by default. You can easily disable it via on of those two query parameters:

- typoTolerance=false: This will disable typo tolerance for all query tokens
- allowTyposOnNumericTokens=false: this will disable typo tolerance on all numbers